# Are ASP.NET MVC 3 Application Web Applications?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Why is there a menu item "Convert to Web Application" in the context menu when you right click on a project that is an ASP.NET MVC 3?

Are they compiled into one assembly by default, or do they act more like a Web Site project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MVC3 projects are compiled apps and are comparable to web applications. I would think that the context menu item would disappear in the service pack. AFAIK, it doesn't do anything on the MVC projects anyway.